# A generic construct requires that the type 'Cell<'T>' is an unmanaged type

Tags: c#, .net, f#, native, unmanaged

Why I cannot have generic unmanaged struct in F#? May be `Cell<'T when 'T: unmanaged>` is not unmanaged, then how I can fix that?

```
type FloatCell =
    struct
        val x: float
        val y: nativeptr<FloatCell>
    end
    
[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type Cell<'T when 'T: unmanaged> =
    struct
        val x: 'T
        val y: nativeptr<Cell<'T>>
    end
```

Gives

> error FS0001: A generic construct requires that the type 'Cell<'T>' is an unmanaged type [E:\dzmitry\src\uncorefx\src\uncorefx\uncorefx.fsproj]

**UPDATE:**

C# has same.

```
   unsafe struct FloatCell
    {
        public float val;
        public FloatCell* next;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    unsafe struct Cell<T> where T: unmanaged
    {
        public float val;
        public Cell<T>* next;
    }
```

With error:

> error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Program.Cell')

I do not think it is managed.

**UPDATE2:**

I tried attributes. Did not help.
I have used extension property for cast. Possible solution. But question why I cannot do that natively? Or I can do? Or should I raise C#/F# issue?

```
[<Struct>]
[<NativeCppClass>]
[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.UnsafeValueType>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type Cell<'T when 'T: unmanaged> =
    struct
        val element: 'T
        val next:  voidptr
    end    

type Cell<'T when 'T: unmanaged> with
    member  x.Next = x.next |> NativePtr.ofVoidPtr<'T>
```

**UPDATE3:**

I have tried to wrap up pointers, and got into the issue without pointers.

```
    public struct UnmanagedStruct
    {
    }

    public struct UnmanagedStructWithSpecifiedGenerics
    {
        public EmptyCell<float> cell;
    }

    public ref struct RefUnmanagedStruct
    {
        public EmptyCell<float> cell;
    }

    public  struct EmptyCell<T> where T : unmanaged
    {
    }
```

And then instantiate:

```
        var compiles1 = new UnmanagedStructWithSpecifiedGenerics();
        var compiles2 = new EmptyCell<UnmanagedStruct>();
        var CS8377_1 = new EmptyCell<EmptyCell<float>>();
        var CS8377_1 = new EmptyCell<UnmanagedStructWithSpecifiedGenerics>();
        var CS0306 = new EmptyCell<RefUnmanagedStruct>();
```

Leads to:

> error CS8377: The type 'EmptyCell' must be a non-nullable value type, along with all fields at any level of nesting, in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'EmptyCell'
>
> error CS8377: The type 'UnmanagedStructWithSpecifiedGenerics' must be a non-nullable value type, along with all fields at any level of nesting, in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'EmptyCell'
>
> error CS0306: The type 'RefUnmanagedStruct' may not be used as a type argument

Wrong error message? Should I raise issue onto Roslyn compiler?

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be by design, though I'm not sure of the reason for the limitation.  Here's a quote from the [F# spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf):

> #### 5.2.9 Unmanaged Constraints
>
> An *unmanaged constraint* has the following form: 
>   `typar : unmanaged`
>
> During constraint solving (§14.5), the constraint `type : unmanaged` is met if *type* is unmanaged as specified below:
>
> - Types `sbyte`, `byte`, `char`, `nativeint`, `unativeint`, `float32`, `float`, `int16`, `uint16`, `int32`, `uint32`, `int64`, `uint64`, `decimal` are unmanaged.
> - Type `nativeptr<type>` is unmanaged.
> - A non-generic struct type whose fields are all unmanaged types is unmanaged.

Note *non-generic* struct types are explicitly mentioned in the last bullet.

Comment: I will try to compile pure IL class to see if this is limitation of C#/F# or of CLR.